# ASP.net IIS Error Message (Screenshot included)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm creating a new ASP.net website via Visual Studio. I then try to run the default.aspx page it generates, and it throws this error:

[image]

I've tried deleting the affected lines as suggested by MSDN but to no avail! I am on Windows 7, with ASP.net installed

If I delete all the lines I get:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the message when you have deleted the lines?

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/04/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html already? I see your application isnt setup this way but maybe you could try out the setting proposed and see if it helps?

Comment: @Tim, updated question with another screenshot

Comment: @Sane, I've added those lines in as suggested, but it throws same errors

Comment: Is the web.config in the website1 folder or in the wwwroot? Is there a web.config in the wwwroot?

Comment: There is a web.config in website1 folder, but there isn't one in the wwroot folder.

Comment: @Tom I think that we need all the web.config with the configSections, and the settings for each one, even with out the exactly parameters... to check it more. This sections are go together with the next configurations lines that they set on the name property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the virtual folder for you application in IIS.

Just dropping it as a folder under the default web site isn't enough.